# How to pass dynamic params in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I want some of my model attributes to predefined dynamically. I have various models.And now I want  My **Bill** model to create objects using other model instances.

*Models :*

```
    leave.rb        # belongs_to :residents
    resident.rb     # has_many:leaves,has_many:bills,has_one:account
    bill.rb         # belongs_to:residents
    rate_card.rb    # belongs_to:hostel
    account.rb      # belongs_to:resident
    hostel.rb
```

now here is my *bills controller*  create method :

```
def create
    @bill = Resident.all.each { |resident| resident.bills.create(?) }
    if @bill.save
      flash[:success]="Bills successfully generated"
    else
      flash[:danger]="Something went wrong please try again !"
    end
  end
```

I want to build bill using all of the models **eg:**

```
resident.bills.create(is_date:using form,to_date:using form,expiry_date:using form,amount:30*(resident.rate_card.diet)+resident.rate_card.charge1+resident.rate_card.charge2)+(resident.account.leaves)*10+resident.account.fine)
///////Is this possible ?
```

***And how to use strong params here ?***

Pls help me out thxx..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Rails way for this logic you want is with `callbacks` if you want *calculated* attributes either on **create**, **update** or **delete**, meaning attributes that depend on other models. For instance:

```
class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  before_create :set_amount

  ...

  protected

    def set_amount
      self.amount = 30 * self.resident.rate_card.diet + self.resident.rate_card.charge1 + self.resident.rate_card.charge2 + (self.resident.account.leaves) * 10 + self.resident.account.fine
    end
end
```

If you want this logic to be used when updating the record also, then you should use `before_save` instead of `before_create`.

After you do this, you should accept the usual params (strong) of Bill model, as in:

```
def bill_params
  params.require(:bill).permit(:is_date, :to_date, :expiry_date)
end
```

So your `create` call would be like:

```
resident.bills.create(bill_params)
```

Also, be wary of your `create` **action**, you should probably create a method either on your `Bill` or your `Resident` model that uses transactions to create all bills at the same time because you probably want either every bill created or none. This way you won't have the `Resident.all.each` logic in your `BillsController`.

Comment: `@bill = Resident.all.each { |resident| resident.bills.create(bill_params) }`
I m using this code to generate bills for all residents .. is it correct ?

Comment: Actually `Resident.all.each ...` will return an array of **Resident**, so that assignment is incorrect. Apart from that, `if @bill.save` wouldn't be correct either since you are already using `create` method which internally `saves` the object, so maybe you meant `build`. That's why I told you that you should create this logic elsewhere, using a `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` (which rollbacks if everything inside if an exception occurred), either in `Resident` model, `Bill` model or a **PORO** class like @Lanny Bose suggested which looks like an elegant solution.

Comment: but the problem is coming at  this method 
`def set_amount
      self.amount = 30 * self.resident.rate_card.diet + self.resident.rate_card.charge1 + self.resident.rate_card.charge2 + (self.resident.account.leaves) * 10 + self.resident.account.fine
    end`
giving this error 
`undefined method `daily_diet' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: i think we can't use those messages here in bill.rb model file ? what do you think ?

Comment: Yes you could, I don't really know what `daily_diet` method is since you haven't mentioned before., maybe if you give a little more context I could help you (maybe it's used in a method on `RateCard` model?)

Comment: see I have list of models  shown above  in my question and rate_card is an model in my app ...now my  question is Can We use `self.resident.hostel.rate_card.daily_diet`  @ in bill model file ? but it is showing error,explained  above  in comment .
U can see the relations btw the models ....scroll above.

Comment: Ok, you did mention a `diet` method and `self.resident.rate_card.diet` not `self.resident.hostel.rate_card.daily_diet`. That message means that rate_card is `nil` for that `hostel` - check that the resident's hostel has a rate_card defined for every resident, otherwise that line of code won't work.

Answer (score 1):

`create` takes a hash, you can:

```
create_params = { amount: 30*(resident.rate_card.diet) }
create_params[:some_field] = params[:some_field]
# and so on
resident.bills.create(create_params)
```

or:

```
obj = resident.bills.build(your_strong_parameters_as_usual)
obj.amount = # that calculation
obj.save!
```

Comment: why r u equating  create_parms with parms ??

Comment: @Nischaynamdev that's assignment to a hash key so that `create_params` becomes `{ amount: 30*(resident.rate_card.diet), some_field: 'some_value_from_params'}`

Comment: Should I use those with strong parameters in private method @ in controller ??

Comment: @Nischaynamdev you do not have to, plus `resident` is a local variable. Strong parameters are not really needed here, because you will be doing a part of their job, but `params.require` will be useful, as it adds presence check

Comment: @Nischaynamdev took a second look at the question, see updated answer. You can `build` object from parameters, assign dynamic ones and only then `save!`

Comment: So , then I must  mot permit amount in strong parameters and other dynamic attributes!! only permitted values will be those who are filled using form right ?

Comment: @Nischaynamdev yes, that's one of the main purposes of strong parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused at your syntax of your controller. `@bill` is being set to the value of a loop, which feels off. Each loops return the enumerable you cycle through, so you'll end up with `@bill = Resident.all` with some bills being created on the side.

What your controller really wants to know is, did my *many* new bills save correctly?

This seems like a perfect place to use a ruby object (or, colloquially, a Plain Old Ruby Object, as opposed to an ActiveRecord object) to encapsulate the specifics of this bill-generator.

If I'm reading this right, it appears that you are generating many bills at once, based on form-inputted data like:

- `is_date`
- `to_date`
- `expiry_date`

...as well as some data about each individual resident.

Here's the model I'd create:

**app/models/bill_generator.rb**

```
class BillGenerator
  include ActiveModel::Model
  # This lets you do validations

  attr_accessor :is_date, :to_date, :expiry_date
  # This lets your form builder see these attributes when you go form.input

  attr_accessor :bills
  # ...for the bills we'll be generating in a sec

  validates_presence_of :is_date, :to_date, :expiry_date
  # You can do other validations here. Just an example.

  validate :bills_are_valid?

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    super # This calls the Active Model initializer
    build_new_bills # Called as soon as you do BillGenerator.new
  end

  def build_new_bills
    @bills = []
    Resident.all.each do |r|
      @bills << r.bills.build(
        # Your logic goes here. Not sure what goes into a bill-building...
        # Note that I'm building (which means not-yet-saved), not creating
      ) 
    end

  def save
    if valid?
      @bills.each { |b| b.save }
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

  private

    def bills_are_valid?
      bill_validity = true
      @bills.each do |b|
        bill_validity = false unless b.valid?
      end
      bill_validity
    end

end
```

Why all this mess? Because in your controller you can do...

**app/controllers/bill_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @bill_generator = BillGenerator.new(bill_generator_params)
  if @bill_generator.save?
     # Redirect to somewhere with a flash?
  else
     # Re-render the form with a flash?
  end
end

def bill_generator_params
  params.require(:bill_generator).permit(:is_date, :to_date, :expiry_date)
  # No extra garbage. No insecurity by letting all kinds of crud through!
end
```

...like a `BillGenerator` is any old object. Did it save? Great. It didn't, show the form again.

Now, my `BillGenerator` won't just be copy-and-paste. Your 'build_new_bills' probably will have some of that math you alluded to, which I'll leave to you.

Let me know what you think!

Comment: how to generate bills for all residents ?

Comment: @Nischaynamdev on the `@bill_generator = BillGenerator.new(bill_generator_params)` line he's already doing that since it calls the `initialize` method on `BillGenerator`.

Comment: what is BillGenerator ? are u referring this to my bill model ?

Comment: It's a class I created specifically to process this form. It's not an ActiveRecord model, so your database won't have any BillGenerators in it. Instead, it's an object that generates bills for you.

Comment: @Nischaynamdev You can read more about this design pattern here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects

Comment: ohk... but the other guy gave me solution and  that worked for me !!...
btw Ur solution was also good... thnx.. :)

Answer (score -1):

you can do it by using `params.permit!` as this allows any parameters to be passed.  here's an example:

```
def create
  ...
  @bill = Resident.all.each { |resident| resident.bills.create(any_params) }
end

private
def any_params
  params.permit!
end
```

be careful with this of course, as you are opening this up to potential exploits.

Comment: `amount:30*(resident.rate_card.diet)+resident.rate_card.charge1+resident.rate_card.charge2)+(resident.account.leaves)*10+resident.account.fine)`
Is it also correct? cuz I have not implemented that code  yet!

Comment: looks like an equation for calculating rent?  i couldn't say if it's "correct" or not, as i'm not familiar with the requirements of the program.